# Could SimpleConnectionPool method work with a pgpass file?

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2, connection-pooling

I'm trying to create a connection pool using `SimpleConnectionPool` method but without specifying a password. As the theory goes, `libpq` should check user's home directory in order to read the `passfile` and establish the connection.

```py
pool = SimpleConnectionPool(1, 20, user="USERNAME", host="HOSTNAME", port="PORTNUMBER", database="SCHEMA")
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
psycopg2.OperationalError: connection to server at "HOSTNAME", port PORTNUMBER failed: fe_sendauth: no password supplied
```

I guess a `passfile` could only be used with the `connect` method, but has anyone here tried to make it work with a `ConnectionPool`?

Comment: It works with .pgpass.  Did you use the same connection parameters with the pool as you did when testing it while not using the pool?

Comment: Yes, pretty much. Although SimpleConnectionPool method doesn't use connection parameters specified as a libpq connection string

Comment: I don't know what you mean by it doesn't use connection parameters, but that certainly makes it sound like they are not the same.

Comment: I mean that by using connect method I can use a connection string like this: psycopg2.connect("'host='HOSTNAME' dbname='SCHEMA' user='USERNAME'"),
whereas by using SimpleConnectionPool method I have to separate them like this
psycopg2.SimpleConnectionPool(user="USERNAME", host="HOSTNAME", ...). I don't know if that makes any difference in order for the library to use a pgpass file with the former but not with the latter

Comment: I can't replicate that either.  SimpleConnectionPool  will accept the same single-string connection string that psycopg2.connet does (preceded by the pool size ints).  Your example though is invalid due to a stray quote.